# typeahead prefetch data from controller

Tags: javascript, jquery, autocomplete, typeahead

I am using typeahead.js for creating a bit more specific autocomplete form field. It has to work dynamically so I used "remote" option, but I need to implement something like this: That field have to fire dropdown menu automatically on click in to it, if the size of resultset of prefetched data is less then 10. If not it has to work default as autocomplete field for minLength 3 letters. How to implement all theese reqiurements?

What I have done is this:

```
$('#client-select').typeahead({
    name: 'users',
    prefetch: "URL?query=''",
    remote: 'URL?query=%QUERY',
    template: [
            '<p class="autocomplete-name">{{surname}} {{name}}</p>',
            '<div>' +
                    '<span class="autocomplete-city">{{city}}</span>' +
                    '<span class="autocomplete-dateofbirth">{{dateOfBirth}}</span>' +
            '</div>'
    ].join(''),
    engine: Hogan,
    limit: 10,
    minLength: 3
});
```

Comment: you are using angular strap typeahead??

Comment: because they have quite similar syntax